# How to remove final_price where clause in magento

Tags: magento

I'm getting missing item return on category list because of the incorrect minimum final_price on the query. How can I remove or fix it? Thanks!

```
SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`brand`, `e`.`brand_value`, `e`.`price_rental_per_week`, `e`.`is_sale`, `e`.`is_imported`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(`price_index`.`tier_price`, LEAST(`price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`), `price_index`.`min_price`) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `pr_catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`  
1    <!-- SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`brand`, `e`.`brand_value`, `e`.`price_rental_per_week`, `e`.`is_sale`, `e`.`is_imported`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(`price_index`.`tier_price`, LEAST(`price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`), `price_index`.`min_price`) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `pr_catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
2    INNER JOIN `pr_catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='66'      2    INNER JOIN `pr_catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='66'
3    INNER JOIN `pr_catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 WHERE ((final_price >= "3610.0000" and final_price <= "7461.0000")) ORDER BY `price_index`.`min_price` desc LIMIT 15
```

Comment: what exactly you want to get and in which file can you please mention ...

Comment: I want to display the correct items. When you visit : http://premierrentals.com.au/catering-equipment/beverage-equipment/coffee-equipment/hot-water-urn.html?dir=desc&order=price and change the sortby to ascending, there is a missing item. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you posted the correct link? You use a module to extend layered navigation with price ranges. Maybe there are still url params set for you.